# A wrong proof for an (evident) lemma

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

(*Eliashberg, Y.; Mishachev, N.M.*, [**Wrinkling of smooth mappings and its applications. I**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002220050188), Invent. Math. 130, No.2, 345-369 (1997). [ZBL0896.58010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0896.58010). \cite{EM})

> Let $ \alpha  : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$  is a 1-dimensional wrinkle. Then for
>   any positive numbers $s_1, \dots , s_l $ such that  $ s:= \sum\nolimits_{1}^{l} s_i \ge
>  {\text{span} \left(\alpha \right)} $, there exists a wrinkled map
>   $\beta : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $\left( s - \text{span}
>  \left(\alpha \right) \right)$-close to $\alpha$ in $C^0$-norm,
>   coincides with $\alpha$ near the end-points of the interval $[a,b],$ 
>   and which has exactly $l$ wrinkles whose spans are equal to $s_1,
>  \dots , s_l$.

I prove for the case $l=2$.

By hypothesis, $\alpha $ is a cubic function with two critical points $c, d \in  \left[ a, b \right] , a< c<d<b$, such that $c$ is the maximum and $d$ is the minimum. 
For convenience, we assume $\alpha (d)=0$. It implies that $\alpha (c) =\text{span}(\alpha)$.
Let $\varepsilon := s_1+s_2 -  \text{span} \left(\alpha \right)$. 
We have to prove that there is a wrinkled map $\beta : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$
such that $\beta$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $\alpha$ in $C^0$-norm, coincides with $\alpha$ near $a, b$, and has $2$ wrinkles $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ whose spans are equal to $s_1, s_2.$

The required function $\beta$ is a wrinkled map, i.e., by definition, there are disjoint subsets $[a_1, e_1]$ and $[e_2, b_1]$, where $a \le a_1 \le e_1  \le e_2 \le b_1 \le b$, of the interval $[a,b]$ such that over them, $\beta$ are wrinkles, which we denoted $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$; and outside them, $\beta$ is a submersion.
For the points $a_1 \le e_1  \le e_2 \le b_1 $ in $[a,b]$ will be chosen later, we can define $\beta$ by
$$ \beta :=
\begin{cases} 
 \text{a smooth path connected } a \text{ and } a_1 \text{ which is a  submersion};\\
 \alpha_1 \text{ is a one-dimensional wrinkle on } [a_1, e_1];\\
 \text{a smooth path connected } e_1 \text{ and } e_2 \text{ which is a  submersion};\\ 
 \alpha_2 \text{ is a one-dimensional wrinkle on } [e_2, b_1]; \\
 \text{a smooth path connected } b_1 \text{ and } b \text{ which is a  submersion}.
\end{cases}$$
The required functions $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are cubic,
hence it suffices to indicate four independent equations for each $\alpha_i, i=1, 2$.

If we suppose $\alpha_1$ reaches maximum at $c$ and $\alpha_2$ reaches minimum at $d$, we would get two equations for each $\alpha_i, i=1,2$. 
$$ \begin{cases} 
 \alpha_1 (c) := t_1;\\
 \alpha_1^\prime (c) = 0;
\end{cases} 
\text{ and }
 \begin{cases} 
\alpha_2 (d) := t_2;\\
 \alpha_2^\prime (d) = 0;
\end{cases} 
$$
where the values $t_1$ and $ t_2$ will be chosen later, such that the condition that $\beta$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $\alpha$ in $C^0$-norm holds, i.e., 
\begin{equation}\label{chopeq232} \begin{cases}
\Vert \alpha - \alpha_1 \Vert_{C^0[a_1, e_1]} = \mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{x \in [a_1, e_1]} \vert \left( \alpha - \alpha_1 \right)(x)  \vert < \varepsilon; \\
\Vert \alpha - \alpha_2 \Vert_{C^0[e_2, b_1]} = \mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{x \in [e_2, b_1]} \vert \left( \alpha - \alpha_2 \right)(x)  \vert < \varepsilon. 
\end{cases}  \end{equation} 
The point $c$ is the critical point of both functions $\alpha $ and $ \alpha_1$ on $[a_1, e_1]$, so the derivative
$$ \left( \alpha - \alpha_1 \right)^\prime (c) = \alpha^\prime (c)  - \alpha_1^\prime (c) = 0.$$ 
Therefore $c$ is one of two critical points of $\alpha - \alpha_1 $  on $[a_1, e_1]$. We could choose, for example, 
$$t_1:= \alpha(c)+ \varepsilon = \text{span}(\alpha)+\varepsilon,$$
then $ \vert \left( \alpha - \alpha_1 \right)(c)  \vert = \varepsilon.$ 
Similarly $d$ is one of two critical points of $\alpha - \alpha_2 $  on  $[e_2,b_1]$. We could choose, 
$$t_2:= \alpha(d) - \varepsilon =  -\varepsilon,$$ 
then $ \vert \left( \alpha - \alpha_2 \right)(d)  \vert = \varepsilon.$
Now we want to find the other extremum of $\alpha - \alpha_1 $  on $[a_1, e_1]$ and of $\alpha - \alpha_2 $  on  $[e_2,b_2]$.

Because the spans of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are equal to $s_1, s_2$, we have one more equation for each wrinkle $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.
$$  \begin{cases}
\mathop{\text{min}}\limits_{x \in [a_1, e_1]} \alpha_1 (x) = \mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{x \in [a_1, e_1]} \alpha_1 (x)  - s_1 =  \text{span}(\alpha)+\varepsilon -s_1 =s_2;\\ % \text{span}(\alpha)+ s_1 + s_2  -\text{span}(\alpha)  -s_1 =  
\mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{x \in [e_2, b_1]} \alpha_2 (x) = \mathop{\text{min}}\limits_{x \in [e_2, b_1]} \alpha_2 (x) + s_2 = s_2 - \varepsilon. 
\end{cases}  $$
We define the minimum value of $\alpha$ on $[a_1, e_1]$ and the maximum of $\alpha$ on $[e_2, b_1]$ so that the condition $\varepsilon$-close to $\alpha$ in $C^0$-norm holds:
$$  
\mathop{\text{min}}\limits_{x \in [a_1, e_1]} \alpha (x) := s_2 + \varepsilon, \text{ and }
\mathop{\text{max}}\limits_{x \in [e_2, b_1]} \alpha (x)  := s_2 - 2 \varepsilon.
  $$
Let 
$$  \begin{cases}
e_0 := \alpha^{-1} \left(s_2 + \varepsilon\right);\\ 
e_3 := \alpha^{-1} \left(s_2 - 2 \varepsilon\right).
\end{cases}  $$
Thus we defined two cubic functions, $f_1$ reaches maximum at $c$ with value $ \text{span}(\alpha) + \varepsilon$ and minimum at $e_0$ with value $s_2$; and $f_2$  reaches maximum at $e_3$ with value $ s_2 - 2 \varepsilon $ and minimum at $d$ with value $-\varepsilon$. The intersections of $f_1$ and $\alpha$ give us two points, which we denoted $(a_1,\alpha_1(a_1))$, $(e_1,\alpha_1(e_1))$; and the intersections of $f_2$ and $\alpha$ give us two other points, which we denoted $(e_2, \alpha_2(e_2))$, $(b_1,\alpha_2(b_1))$. Finally we get the wrinkles $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.
In conclusion, for the given conditions, we could construct a wrinkled map $\beta$ which is $\varepsilon$-closed to $\alpha$ in $C^0$-norm, coincides with $\alpha$ near $a, b$, and has two wrinkles $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ whose spans are $s_1, s_2$.

Unfortunately it is wrong. In fact as the construction, the $C^0$-norm of $\alpha_1-\alpha$ would be greater than $\epsilon$. The point is, I constructed $ e_0 $ to be the point which $\alpha_1$ reaches its local minimum $s_2$ and $\alpha(e_0)=s_2+\epsilon$. But $\alpha_1-\alpha$ does not reach its local minimum at $ e_0$.

**Vague idea:** the equations and inequalities for $\alpha_1$ are:

1)     Maximality at $c$;

2)     Span$(\alpha_1)$ equals $s_1$;

3)     Value at $a$ (or $a_1$);

4)     [Inequality] range of $\alpha_1-\alpha$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.

I am really need your help. I only got so far. To specify everything, like the existence of the solution, I don't know...
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Great first post (good formatting). Deserves a +1 from me.